# Get text from bs4.element.Tag containing JSON (beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I have an element with type `bs4.element.Tag` like:

```html
<span class="hidden gtm-product-data">
{"id":"716727616125500","name":"chinese whitewine","price":7.99,"brand":"silver heights"}
</span>
```

The span-tag contains a JSON string.
How to extract only the brand name (JSON field `brand`s value) `silver heights`?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```py
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = '<span class="hidden gtm-product-data">{"id":"716727616125500","name":"chinese white wine","price":7.99,"brand":"silver heights"}</span>'

soup = json.loads(BeautifulSoup(sample, 'html.parser').find("span").getText())["brand"]
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
silver heights
```